# Reference Parameter to Lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, boost

When passing a lambda expression to a function, can I store that lambda/closure somewhere for later use even after that function returns?

As I understand a lambda generates a temporary unnamed function object, which is destroyed after the function returns.

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig;

void foo()
{
    sig.connect([]{ /* do something */ });
}

int main()
{
    foo();

    sig();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A code sample and a description of what you're trying to do would go a long way here.  Otherwise the answer is either "yes" or "no."  Doesn't C++ allow "bare methods," not requiring you to define a class?

Comment: Yup I added some code. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What does `sig();` call in your example? Is this hypothetical code, or code that actually works?

Comment: Please try read the code, it's not that long. :)

Comment: I did.  Granted, I'm not a C++ guru, but shouldn't that `sig()` be attached to an object somewhere, or at least some method declaration?

Comment: Yup it's. When foo() is called, the sig is bound to the lambda expression.

Comment: And this actually compiles and executes successfully?

Comment: Try it yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Lambda closures are not magic. They work just like any other object. You can pass them by-reference or by-value, make copies and store them for later use. As long as you don't play nasty tricks, they will behave as expected.

It gets more tricky when it comes to the life-time of the objects captured by-reference in the closure. Lambdas don't magically turn C++ into a managed language. Once the scope of the objects ends, they will be destroyed and any references the closure might keep will dangle, waiting to explode later. If you wish to keep a lambda closure for longer than the scope will last that contains the captured objects, you'll be better off capturing by-value. In rare cases, you might want to use `std::shared_ptr`s (which you'd capture by-value).

One final thing to be aware of is that non-capturing lambdas are implicitly convertible to function pointers. Once this conversion happens, the closure object may be destroyed and the function pointer will behave just like any other function pointer.

If you are confused by lambda expressions, I recommend you replace them – in your imagination or on a throw-away copy of your code – with a manually written instantiation of a `struct` that has data members for each captured object and an overloaded `operator()`. You should then be able to reason about the code more comfortably.

Comment: void func() {
           int a;
           thread myThread( [&a] { /* do something */ } );
}

Comment: @Joseph No, for several reasons: (1) Since you neither `join()` nor `detach()` the `std::thread`, its destructor will call `std::terminate` on scope exit. (2) Assuming you'd call `detach()`, the reference to `a` would dangle. With a `join()` instead of a `detach()`, it would be ok, since you'd keep the scope active until the function completes. I'm assuming that the lambda actually uses `a`.

Comment: In general, please try to ask about complete, self-contained examples. It is difficult to reason about the validity of incomplete snippets.

Comment: My question comes from seeing many examples that pass lambdas (with/out captures) to thread and signal objects in one scope, and then they start the thread/signals from a different scope. Interestingly those objects (threads/signals) take reference to function/objects not a copy. The source of examples is reliable makes me wonder if lambdas closures are treated differently, the generated functor is never destroyed.

Comment: Well, as I've said, I'd need a complete example to reason about.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!